# Converting a dataframe to tidy format

Tags: r

Here I'm attempting to convert dataframe to tibble format and split the year , month column values into their own rows :

```
library(dpylr)
library(tidyr)

res <- data.frame("year.month" = c("2005M1","2005M2","2005M3","2005M4"), "national houses" = c(100,100,100,100), "dublin houses" = c(120,120,120,120))

res %>% separate(year.month , into=c("year" , "month") ,  sep=".")
```

returns :

```
  year month national.houses dublin.houses
1                        100           120
2                        100           120
3                        100           120
4                        100           120
Warning message:
Too many values at 4 locations: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

year & month values are not appearing, im not utilizing separate correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that just separating year from month would get you to half-tidy. 
You still have two separate columns that both count houses. One row per observation, one column per variable would require something like this:

```
res %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key = where, 
                value = houses, 
                -year.month) %>% 
  mutate(where = gsub(where, 
                      pattern = '\\.houses', 
                      replacement = '')) %>% 
  separate(year.month, 
           into = c('year', 'month'), 
           sep = 'M')
```

Comment: can you elaborate on why used -year.month parameter within gather instead of year.month  ? Why use negative operator for year.month ?

Comment: The - in front of a column name or set of names means “but don’t gather these.” Try and see what happens if you delete -year.month.

Comment: I don't entirely agree with your statement: "_separating year from month would get you to half-tidy_." What constitutes as "tidy" depends a lot on context (i.e. There is no single table format that works for all use cases). While a long format (one row per observation) might be cleaner for some operations like plotting and aggregation, the wide format might be more useful for representing counts per month. Your answer being accepted aside, there is not enough information in OP's question to indicate which format is more desirable, IMO.

Comment: I simply used the strict definition “one row per observation, one column per variable.” By this definition longer is tidier; tidier, depending on context, may not also be more useful. I think that’s what you’re getting at and I agree. But my suggestion was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`.` is a wild card in regex, and the `sep` argument in `separate` takes regex, so your code tries to split `year.month` by each character, hence the warning of too many values. The following separates your column correctly using positive lookbehind and lookahead:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res %>% 
  separate(year.month, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "(?<=\\d)(?=M)")
```

You can also use `extract` from `tidyr` to split by capture group:

```
res %>% 
  extract(year.month, into = c("year", "month"), regex = "(\\d{4})(M\\d)")
```

**Result:**

```
  year month national.houses dublin.houses
1 2005    M1             100           120
2 2005    M2             100           120
3 2005    M3             100           120
4 2005    M4             100           120
```